# capistrano version 3 upgrade confusing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-web-services, ssh, capistrano

I am struggling with upgrading capistrano v2 to v3 for 5 days.I am trying to deploy from my local machine to ec2 instance development environment. I can't move further. My trace is here

**$cap development deploy:check**

```
INFO [429e612c] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/my_app_name/ on 70.22.320.14
DEBUG [429e612c] Command: ( RVM_BIN_PATH=~/.rvm/bin /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/my_app_name/ )
 INFO [429e612c] Finished in 6.208 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/my_app_name/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
 INFO Uploading /tmp/my_app_name/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
 INFO [c3a41f2e] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/my_app_name/git-ssh.sh on 70.22.320.14
DEBUG [c3a41f2e] Command: ( RVM_BIN_PATH=~/.rvm/bin /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/my_app_name/git-ssh.sh )
 INFO [c3a41f2e] Finished in 0.720 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [c5891dcc] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:example/webapp.git
 on 70.22.320.14
DEBUG [c5891dcc] Command: ( RVM_BIN_PATH=~/.rvm/bin GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/my_app_name/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote  git@github.com:example/webapp.git
DEBUG [c5891dcc]    /usr/bin/env: 
DEBUG [c5891dcc]    git
DEBUG [c5891dcc]    : No such file or directory
DEBUG [c5891dcc]    
DEBUG [c5891dcc] Finished in 0.664 seconds with exit status 127 (failed).
```

**config/deploy.rb**

```
set :application, 'my_app_name'
set :repo_url, '.'
set :branch, 'master'
set :scm, :git
set :deploy_to, "/home/ec2-user/capistrano-3/}"
set :ssh_options, {:keys => ["#{ENV['HOME']}/.ssh/my_pem.pem"], :forward_agent =>true}
set :keep_releases, 5
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.0.0-p353'
set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin' }
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :deploy_via, :copy

set :log_level, :debug
set :pty, true
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}


SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake]  = "bundle exec rake"
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rails] = "bundle exec rails"

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      # execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'

end
```

**config/deploy/development.rb**

```
set :stage, :development


role :app, %w{ec2-user@70.22.320.14}
role :web, %w{ec2-user@70.22.320.14}
role :db,  %w{ec2-user@70.22.320.14}
role :all,  %w{ec2-user@70.22.320.14}

server 'ec2-user@70.22.320.14', user: 'ec2-user', roles: %w{web app}
```

**Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

My problems:

1. My git path is not accepted
2. ssh key problems

git and ssh keys work with capistrano 2 for the same app I am deploying. Upgrading to capistrano v3 gives a bigger head-ache. What can I do consecutively. Kindly guide me through the correct steps

Comment: No need to `SSHKit.config.command_map` `:rake` and `:rails`, `capistrano/bundler` takes care of that.

Comment: Also, only one of `server` and `role :app/:web/:db` is needed. In this case I think `server` overrides the specific `:app/:web/:db`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have spent some time struggling with capistrano3 and here are some hints, probably they can be useful:

1) Official manual [capistranorb.com](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/). There are tips about what you should do consecutively. Section about authentication and authorisation also helpful. There are some hints about ssh configuring on workstation and on server. I have followed on this guide and it helps me. Try to build your deploy.rb by following this guide from scratch.

Also helpful guides: [guide1](http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2014/01/deploying-rails-apps-to-a-vps-with-capistrano-v3/), [guide2](https://github.com/jesson/capistrano3-nginx_unicorn)

2) Here is my Capfile. Notice rvm1/capistrano3 and capistrano3/unicorn. Very useful gems.

```
    require 'capistrano/setup'

    require 'capistrano/deploy'
    require 'capistrano3/unicorn'
    require 'rvm1/capistrano3'
    require 'capistrano/rvm'
    require 'capistrano/bundler'
    require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
    require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
```

3) You can try the command:

```
ssh ubuntu@ec2....amazonaws.com -v
```

or

```
ssh git@github.com -v   # from your EC2 server
```

to understand what happens when you try connect to your EC2 server. Probably the problem with pem key? Create .pub key and try to use it. Don't forget to add it to the ~/ssh/authorized_keys

```
cat id_rsa_aws.pub | ssh ubuntu@....amazonaws.com "cat >>   
/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

configure your ssh-agent and don't forget to add in your ~/.bash_profile something like this:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_deploy_github
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_digital_ocean
```

If you have problems with ssh, probably you should look at this [ssh-guide](http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/10/24/ssh-key-and-passwordless-login-basics-for-developers/)

Also you can watch my app, where i am using capistrano3. Probably you can find there something for you: [#project](https://github.com/DavydenkovM/Touching-axlsx)

P.s. On some VPS git is not installed, so it is good idea to check:

```
deployer@ec2***.amazonaws.com$ which git
```

if not found:

```
deployer@ec2***.amazonaws.com$ sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: My remote serverdoes not contain git. So I added git in my remote. Now my problem solved